# Spectral resolutions of a second-order orthogonal tensor

Tags: tensors, spectral-theory

Page 37 of [Continuum mechanics by C. S. Jog](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/continuum-mechanics/8E4AE467BC749395284A5A34B3BCC25F) lists the following formulae as the "spectral resolutions" of an orthogonal tensor $\bf R$ as having the eigenvectors ${\bf e} , \, {\bf n} , \, {\bf \hat{n}}$ and the corresponding eigenvalues $1, \lambda , \hat{\lambda}$, where ${\bf n}$ and ${\bf \hat{n}}$ are complex conjugates.

$$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
{\bf I} & = {\bf e} \otimes {\bf e} +  {\bf n} \otimes {\bf \hat{n}} + {\bf \hat{n}} \otimes {\bf n} \\
{\bf R} & = {\bf e} \otimes {\bf e} +  \lambda \; {\bf n} \otimes {\bf \hat{n}} + \hat{\lambda} \; {\bf \hat{n}} \otimes {\bf n} \\
{\bf R}^2 & = {\bf e} \otimes {\bf e} +  \lambda^2 \; {\bf n} \otimes {\bf \hat{n}} + \; \hat{\lambda}^2 {\bf \hat{n}} \otimes {\bf n} \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
$$

I'd appreciate help deriving these "spectral resolutions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I finally have the answer with help from the author. What follows is a sketch of the proof.*

First, because the eigenvalues $1$, $\lambda$ and $\hat{\lambda}$ are distinct they are linearly independent (see a simple proof [here](https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~novozhil/Teaching/329%20Data/12.pdf#page=2)). Next because the eigenvalues of $\bf R$ are linearly independent it can be expressed as the product of three matrices

$$
{\bf R} = {\bf P} \, {\bf \Lambda} \, {\bf P}^{-1}
$$

Proof given [here](https://www.math.ust.hk/~mabfchen/Math111/Week11-12.pdf#page=6), where $\bf P$ is the the matrix whose columns consist of the eigenvectors $\bf e$, $\bf n$ and $\bf \hat{n}$ and $\bf \Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are the eigenvalues $1$, $\lambda$ and $\hat{\lambda}$ i.e.

$$
{\bf P} = [ \, {\bf e} \, , \,  {\bf n} \, , \, {\bf \hat{n}} \, ]
$$

$$
\Lambda = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \hat{\lambda}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Because

$${\bf P} = e_1 \otimes {\bf e} \, + \,e_2 \otimes {\bf n} \, + \, e_3 \otimes {\bf \hat{n}}$$

where $e_1 = [1 \, , \, 0 \, , \,  0]^T$, $e_2 = [0 \, , \, 1 \, , \,  0]^T$ and $e_3 = [0 \, , \, 0 \, , \,  1]^T$.

The transpose conjugate is

$${\bf P}^T = {\bf e} \otimes e_1 \, + {\bf \hat{n}} \otimes \,e_2 \, + \, {\bf n}\otimes e_3 $$

Note that the conjugate is taken because $\bf P$ is complex valued. It follows that:

$${\bf P}^T {\bf P} \, = \, {\bf P} \, {\bf P}^T =  \, {\bf I} = \, {\bf e} \otimes {\bf e} \, + \,{\bf n} \otimes {\bf \hat{n}} \, + \,  {\bf \hat{n}} \otimes {\bf n}^T $$

Therefore ${\bf P}^T$ is the inverse of ${\bf P}$, i.e.

$${\bf P}^T = \, {\bf P}^{-1} = \, [ \, {\bf e}^T \, , \,  {\bf n}^T \, , \, {\bf \hat{n}}^T \, ]$$

Therefore

$$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
{\bf R} &= {\bf P} \, {\bf \Lambda} \, {\bf P}^T \\
        &= {\bf e} \, {\bf e}^T \, + \, \lambda \, {\bf n}\, {\bf \hat{n}}^T \, + \, \hat{\lambda}\, {\bf \hat{n}} \, {\bf n} \\
        &= {\bf e} \otimes {\bf e} \, + \, \lambda \, {\bf n} \otimes {\bf \hat{n}} \, + \, \hat{\lambda}\, {\bf \hat{n}} \otimes {\bf n}^T
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
$$